# Get posts that have both of two categories only

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a post in wordpress and selected two categories (e.g: id=20,150). 
Now with a custom `query_post` method, I want to show the post only if it have both of the categories.

For this I wrote this query:

```
$subc = array('20','150');
$query = query_posts('post_type=post&cat='.$subc.'&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=50&paged='. get_query_var('paged'));
```

The query should be treate this way: if categories found are 20 AND 150 then show, otherwise don't display.

But I am not getting exactly what i want. Can anyone modify above query and help me to show exactly what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [don't use `query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts). Ever.

Then, using `get_posts`, you can use the [`category__and`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) parameter:

```
$get_posts = query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category__and' => array(20,150),
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
));
```

Comment: Thanks, your query made my day.. Thanks...:)

Comment: Why "First, don't use query_posts. Ever."?

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins There is a link on "dont use query_post", click it and read it.

Comment: That link goes to an amazing answer!  It's worth a full read.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one?

```
query_posts(array(
  'post_type'=>'post',
  'cat'=>'20,150',
  'post_status'=>'publish',
  'posts_per_page'=>'50',
  'paged'=>get_query_var('paged')
));
```

Comment: Nope, not working. i have just added in one post and its showing me 7 posts,,

Comment: Nope still not working... not getting what exactly i want to show

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822880/wordpress-future-page-issue-not-showing this might help you.